# Application Pool

Tags: iis, application-pool, worker-process

I have some doubts about **Application pool**

1. Multiple application in One Application pool running under the only worker process by default
2. Multiple application in One Application pool We can assign different worker processes for different applications.

Above is my Understanding about Application pool and worker process 
I want to clarity in these concepts, If anybody have please explain me.

Thanks,
Dnyaneshwar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your understanding is almost correct.

- When you create a new web site in IIS it creates an application pool
  for you with the same name as the web site, so in fact the default is
  every web app gets its own application pool.
- You can set single application pool to host multiple IIS web sites. The
  effect is that all the sites sharing the app pool are hosted in the
  same exe. If you restart/recycle this app pool, it will restart all the web
  sites it is being used in.
- You can isolate different web sites by assigning different
  application pools to each web app (as mentioned IIS does this by default)
- One application pool has a single worker process (w3wp.exe) by
  default but but you can increase this.